# DSolve unable to solve known second order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve a second order time dependent differential equation with a known solution. The equations I wish to solve are

$x''[t]=\frac{-x[t]}{(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)^{1.5}}$

and

$y''[t]=\frac{-y[t]}{(x[t]^2+y[t]^2)^{1.5}}$

Clearly this has the solution x[t]=Cos[t+a], y[t]=Sin[t+b], where a and b can be defined depending on the boundary conditions. However when I try and solve this in Mathematica it is unable to return the solution, even if I include boundary conditions.

```
eqns1 = {(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^-1.5*x''[t] == - 
     x[t], (x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^-1.5*y''[t] == - y[t], x[0] == 0, 
   y[0] == 1};
DSolve[eqns1, {x, y}, t]
```

However this returns

```
DSolve[{(x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^1.5 == -x[t], (
    y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]/(x[t]^2 + y[t]^2)^1.5 == -y[t], x[0] == 0, 
  y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, t]
```

i.e. it is just telling me that Mathematica cannot solve this. Does anyone know why I cannot get a solution or what the problem is? Is there a known way to work around this?

Thanks

Comment: It's known from Newtons law of gravity. Basically saying if I orbit a spherically symmetric body I will do so in a circle. I would also argue if I give you the solution it is a known ODE. The solutions I have are obvious from the angle I was approaching the problem from

Comment: `Sqrt&Co` often causes problems in ode solving. `NDSolve` with appropriate initial  conditions solves your problem!

Comment: Hi Ulrich, thanks for the comment. I am aware that these equations can be solved numerically, but I require an analytic solution for when I extend to slightly higher potentials

Comment: Unfortunately, there are many seemingly elementary ODEs that `DSolve` cannot solve.  Considering transforming the equations to polar coordinates.